# Схема предложения при стыке союзов

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, слово "то" будет выноситься за скобки или входить в главную часть?  И как в такой ситуации быть с продолжением союза, где слова "так", "тем"?

[Впереди показалась широкая река], и (когда всадники подъехали), то [увидели], (что мост снесен наводнением).

Или:
[Впереди показалась широкая река], и (когда всадники подъехали), [то увидели], (что мост снесен наводнением).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верен второй вариант.  [ = - ], и (когда  -  =  ), [то = ], (что  - = ).

Между скобками может быть только сочинительный союз, соединяющий равноправные простые предложения, а средства связи СПП распределяются по разным предложениям: подчинительный союз, союзное слово  или первая часть двойного союза находится в придаточном, а указательное слово или вторая часть двойного союза  - в главном.